# Pandas: Sorting columns by their mean value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas, I would like to sort its columns (i.e. get a new dataframe, or a view) according to the mean value of its columns (or e.g. by their std value). The documentation talks about [sorting by label or value](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#sorting-by-index-and-value), but I could not find anything on custom sorting methods.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use the [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) DataFrame method and the Series [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) method:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), columns=list('ABCD'))

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
          A         B         C         D
0  0.933069  1.432486  0.288637 -1.867853
1 -0.455952 -0.725268  0.339908  1.318175
2 -0.894331  0.573868  1.116137  0.508845
3  0.661572  0.819360 -0.527327 -0.925478

In [13]: df.mean()
Out[13]:
A    0.061089
B    0.525112
C    0.304339
D   -0.241578
dtype: float64

In [14]: df.mean().sort_values()
Out[14]:
D   -0.241578
A    0.061089
C    0.304339
B    0.525112
dtype: float64
```

Then you can reorder the columns using [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
In [15]: df.reindex(df.mean().sort_values().index, axis=1)
Out[15]:
          D         A         C         B
0 -1.867853  0.933069  0.288637  1.432486
1  1.318175 -0.455952  0.339908 -0.725268
2  0.508845 -0.894331  1.116137  0.573868
3 -0.925478  0.661572 -0.527327  0.819360
```

---

*Note: In earlier versions of pandas, `sort_values` used to be `order`, but `order` was deprecated as part of 0.17 so to be more consistent with the other sorting methods. Also, in earlier versions, one had to use `reindex_axis` rather than `reindex`.*

Comment: It seems that `order` is now deprecated, and `sort_values` (added in version 0.17.0) should be used instead.

Comment: @bli thank you! I really need to write a script to update all of my pandas answers (I suspect there's a few hundred that could do with an update)....

Comment: sort_values(ascending=False) if you would like a descending order

Comment: also I'd recommend using `reindex` instead of `reindex_axis` as it is flagged as deprecated and about to be removed in a future version (I'm using pandas  v0.23.4)

Comment: Thanks @dvitsios, I updated this answer with your suggestion!

Answer (score 10):

You can use [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create a variable, use it to sort values and drop it in the same line of code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.assign(m=df.mean(axis=1)).sort_values('m').drop('m', axis=1)
```

Comment: .mean(axis=1) finds the mean of rows, not columns.

Comment: This is a nice and intuitive way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

modify from  Adriel M. Vieira:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.T.assign(m=df.mean(axis=0)).sort_values('m').drop('m', axis=1).T
```