# How to make the order of legend according to the average of data line

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I have 8 data lines plotted using matplotlib, the legend are originally ordered related to filename as my code suggests.
I want to however to make the order of legend based on the average value of data line.(from average high to average low, but the legend names still have to be filenames, just change the order)
How do I achieve it?

[image]

my original code:

```
df.plot(x='INDEX', y=range(1, 9, 1))
a = {}
for z in range(0, len(files_in_dir), 1):
    a_string = (files_in_dir[z])
    a[z] = a_string
plt.legend(a.values(), loc = 1)
```

Comment: Your plot isn't reproducible because we don't know what `df` looks like nor do we know what the variable `files_in_dir` refers to. Your question can still be answered by looking at the matplotlib documentation, but just for future reference, you're more likely to get an answer if you provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Although you could modify the legend object itself, I think a simpler workaround it to rearrange the columns in your DataFrame in descending order by their average value.

I created a DataFrame similar to yours with a column called `'INDEX'` which I assume is similar to the format of your DataFrame (but including a sample of your DataFrame in the question would help), and other columns with average values intentionally out of order. Then we can sort columns whose values will be the y-values on the plot (I assume all of the columns except for `'INDEX'` in your DataFrame) by their average value in descending order (credit goes to [Andy Hayden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712163/pandas-sorting-columns-by-their-mean-value/17712440)), and apply the same `df.plot` method.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## reproduce some data where the columns have different averages and are out of order
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'INDEX':list(range(1,65)),
    'consumer aged 25C':np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 64),
    'consumer aged 70C':np.random.normal(2, 0.1, 64),
    'consumer fresh 25C':np.random.normal(1, 0.1, 64),
    'consumer fresh 70C':np.random.normal(5, 0.1, 64)
    })

# df.plot(x='INDEX', y=range(1,5))
## sort the non-INDEX columns of the DataFrame by their average value
df_sorted = df.reindex(
    pd.Index(['INDEX'])
        .append(df.loc[:, df.columns != 'INDEX']
            .mean()
            .sort_values(ascending=False).index), axis=1
    )
df_sorted.plot(x='INDEX', y=range(1,5))
plt.show()
```

[image]